# Iterate through a string array and check for particular substring

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a string which is spliced by vbCrLf into an array.

strArr = Split(string, vbCrLf)

How can I iterate this array and check whether it contains a particular substring.

Let strArr(4) be "This is an example"

How can I check whether strArr(4) contains the substring "example"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
    If InStr(strArr(i), "example") Then
        MsgBox strArr(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I just want to look for the strings containing the substring "example" and not the whole sentence. The above solution wouldn't for example find the second case "This is another example". Can you follow me?

Comment: @Bython No worries. I've updated the answer to reflect your new requirement.

Comment: @Bython Note however, that the comparison IS case sensitive... so, "example" has to be in lower case characters. Do you want it this way? Or, would you prefer to match no matter the case?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the string array and use `indexOf()` to identify the substring, e.g. `strArr(4).indexOf("example")`. A negative return value indicates `strArr(4)` doesn't contain the desired substring; otherwise `strArr(4)` contains it.

`"This is an example".indexOf("example")` will give you `11`, which is the index of the substring `"example"`.

Comment: You do realize this is a VBA question?